# Angular.bootstrap throwing error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to my migrate my website to angular but slowly. Current scenario is i am having a plain HTML login page in which there is a link to open a forget password popup. I have migrated the Forget password page to Angular. So what i am doing is when the user clicks on the link, i load the angular library, controller and application through $.getscript and then do a AJAX call to load the ForgetPassword page content in the popup. I can see in console evrything has loaded prioperly but error comes when i try to bootstrap. Please find below my JS code.The error i am getting in console is "ReferenceError: angular is not defined angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);"

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#complementary-nav ul li a#popup").bind("click", function () {
            loadfiles(function () {
                OpenPopup();
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });
        });
    });
    // Code to open in pop up
    function loadfiles(callback) {
        var scripts = ['/js/angular.min.1.2.9.js', '/js/Controller.js', '/js/application.js'];
        for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
            $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {});
        }
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    }

    function OpenPopup() {
        var url = "/dev/Forgot-Password.aspx";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            async: false,
            contentType: "charset=UTF-8",
            url: url,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#common-popup").html("").append($(data));
                $("#common-popup_overlay").fadeIn(500);                    
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error")
            }
        });
    }
```

The Forgot Password HTML looks like this

```
    <div ng-controller="ForgotPasswordController" id="lostPasswwordOverlayContent" class="overlayContent">

<p>
    <label>E-Mail<span class="mandatory">*</span></label>
    <input type="email" ng-class="{'input-error':(_ServerForm.email.$dirty && _ServerForm.email.$error.emailValidate) || (blankSubmit && _ServerForm.email.$invalid)}" ng-model="user.email" email-validate required name="email" placeholder="" maxlength="100" id="EmailAddress" />
    <span class="ui-state-error h5-message" ng-show="(_ServerForm.email.$dirty && _ServerForm.email.$error.emailValidate) || (blankSubmit && _ServerForm.email.$invalid)">
        <span class="h5-arrow"></span>
        <span class="h5-content">Invalid Email</span>
    </span>
</p>

<div class="button buttonSimple buttonRight greenbutton forgotpassword">
    <a name="fgtpassword" id="fgtpassword" href="#" class="" ng-click="submitform($event)"><span>Submit<span class="visual"></span></span></a>
</div>
```

I have tested the functionality seperately for this page and it works fine if opened an independent HTML page whereas when i try to make changes and open it as a popup, i am getting error

Comment: Your callback handler gets executed before scripts are loaded, so you need to use jquery's getScript callback handler to execute your own callback.

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Can you help me with a snippet on the same. I actually placed a breakpoint in firebug to check the same. i saw in console that files are getting loaded first but again that may be just because i placed the breakpoint

Comment: Try using the loadfiles function in @meilke's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@meilke Yes the solution worked for me. But i found an alternative for doing it .
I am using the modernizr approach for the loading the JS files. With this approach i am also able to load CSS files together with the JS files

```
     $("#complementary-nav ul li a#popup").bind("click", function () {
            loadfiles(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);
            });
        });

     function loadfiles(callback) {
      var modernizrLoad = [{ load: ['//code.angularjs.org/1.2.8/angular.min.js', '/js/application.js', '/js/Controller.js', '/css/Styles_v2.css', '/css/tyles.css'], complete: function () { OpenPopup(callback); } }];
      Modernizr.load(modernizrLoad);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I never used `$.getScript()` but according to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) you can provide a callback when the scripts have arrived and have been executed. Why don't you call your own callback then?

```
function loadfiles(callback) {
    var scripts = ['/js/angular.min.1.2.9.js', '/js/Controller.js', '/js/application.js'];
    var scriptsAlreadyFetched = scripts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        $.getScript(scripts[i], function () {
          scriptsAlreadyFetched--;
          if (typeof callback === "function" && scriptsAlreadyFetched== 0) {
            callback();
          }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same if you see, its just i am not doing it inside the for loop. I am doing it right after my for loop ends

Comment: But at that point, your request for the scripts has not been done yet! Use the `getScript` callback parameter to wait for the scripts being received and evaluated.

Comment: Yes, i changed the logic as per your code snippet but still the issue persist. I am still getting the same error "angular is not defined" on line "angular.bootstrap(document, ['tbs-lybc']);"

Comment: Have you debugged it? Are the files being loaded? Are you being called back? Did you rename the Angular source file (because it is not the standard source file name)?

Comment: Ya i placed a breakpoint inside the if statement inside the for loop. I can see all the files getting loaded. Regarding angular library, yes i have renamed it to keep a check of the version

Comment: Tried it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6BRN/1/) and you are right! I updated my answer with a fix.