# how to trigger angularjs in an external page?

Tags: angularjs

In my process I load my page from a server and I add it to the current page where the user is in. After that the view doesn't load.

Is there a way to trigger angularjs in order to make it load the views, the controllers, and the directives and include them in my page? I don't want to use an iframe, just JavaScript or jQuery.

Comment: Check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426606/angular-bootstrap-throwing-error) question

Comment: maybe do you need to `compile` appended code before.

Comment: do you have an example, or some documentation on it cause it would really help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. It is possible to bootstrap after the fact. Instead of placing the ng-app tag in the content, simply load it into a DIV you can reference, then wire up the DIV like this (assuming your app is named "myApp"):

```
angular.bootstrap(angular.element(appDiv), ['myApp']);
```

Here's a working Fiddle that demonstrates this. It waits one second to simulate loading the page dynamically, copies the contents of a template to the div and then wires up Angular: http://jsfiddle.net/jeremylikness/wMF4x/