# Why angular.bootstrap() to document throws error

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap

I have my test example in this [plunkr link](https://plnkr.co/edit/wkFv9G3rFAjOYrANHczF?p=preview)

My question is NOT DUPLICATE of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21426606/angular-bootstrap-throwing-error)

Also the [Google Result and Github Bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3692) was about the bug reporter *not defining the module which he was trying to bootstrap in the first place*

I have 3 modules `grandParentModule`, `parentModule` and `nestedModule`.

I have **bootstrapped `parentModule` and `nestedModule` to 2 nested div elements** and they are **working fine.**

**But as soon as I try to bootstrap `grandParentModule` to document, it is throwing a console error.**

**This is my HTML**

```
<div id="parent" ng-app="parentModule">
  <div id="nested">
  </div>
</div>
```

**And this is my SCRIPT**

```
angular.module('grandParentModule', []);
angular.module('parentModule', []);
angular.module('nestedModule', []);

var nestedElem = document.getElementById("nested");

angular.bootstrap(angular.element(nestedElem), ['nestedModule']);

//comment / uncomment this line to toggle the error at console
angular.bootstrap(document, ['grandParentModule']);
```

Only this line `angular.bootstrap(document, ['grandParentModule']);` is causing the error

> Uncaught Error: [ng:btstrpd] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ng/btstrpd?p0=%26lt%3Bdiv%20id%3D%22parent%22%20ng-app%3D%22parentModule%22%26gt%3B

Can anyone explain to me why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how works angular bootstrapping.

You're supposed,to bootstrap only one module.

If you use multiple independant module, the DOM element where you bootstrap them must not be nested.

Furthermore what are those module supposed to be ?

If they're linked then they must have dependencies between them ie :

```
angular.module('parentModule', ['grandParentModule']);
```

If you want to have some nested views with their own controller use either multiple `ng-controller` or check `ui-router` on the net.

Comment: Ok, so you are saying like it is a bad practice and I should not do it and also I will not achieve anything useful by doing it. I get it. **But my question is bootstrapping in nested 'div' are not throwing error. But only bootstrapping with document is throwing error** Isn't that strange?

Comment: Sorry didn't understood it like that. I'm not really sure but i would say that  document is not a DOM element, while `<div>` nested are. It works even on `<html>`.  So this is probably why you have the error.